# Elfinder Connect To Remote Directory

Tags: linux, elfinder

I am trying to connect to remote directory with this setting in elfinder Connector:

> 'path' => '//192.168.1.176/Share/',
>   'URL' => '//192.168.1.176/Share/',

This work fine in windows, but when i moved to linux i got this error message:
"Invalid Backend Configuration. Readable volumes not available"

So, how I got this work under linux?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is a windows share you are trying to connect to.  Linux uses samba to connect to windows shares.  Connect to it with 'smb://192.168.1.176/Share/'.

You may actually need to mount that location on your linux file system to make it work.